# Laravel yajra/datatables & yajra/datatables button

Tags: php, laravel, yajra-datatable

Hi i'm using  yajra/datatables & yajra/datatables-buttons for laravel 5.6.39. I have followed the tutorial http://dt54.yajrabox.com/buttons/query, (that is for 5.4).
I can see buttons, but i'm not able to retrive the data from the DB.
Maybe i'm missing something cause if i try to show the table via Controller i can see data, but of course i can't use export-buttons.... So may you explain what is my missing point here?

PHP Version: 7.1.3

Laravel Version: 5.6.39

Laravel-DataTables Version: 8.0

Laravel-DataTables-Buttons Version: 3.0

---

### This is my Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Orders;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Orders\SupplierOrder;
use App\DataTables\SuppliersOrdersDataTable;
use Carbon;

class SuppliersOrders extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(SuppliersOrdersDataTable $dataTable)
    {
        return $dataTable->render('layout.orders.suppliersOrders.suppliersOrdersTable');
    }
```

### This is my DataTable Model

```
<?php

namespace App\DataTables;

use App\Models\Orders\SupplierOrder;
use Yajra\DataTables\Services\DataTable;
use Carbon;

class SuppliersOrdersDataTable extends DataTable
{
    /**
     * Build DataTable class.
     *
     * @param mixed $query Results from query() method.
     * @return \Yajra\DataTables\DataTableAbstract
     */
    public function dataTable($query)
    {

        return datatables($query)
               ->editColumn('supplier_order_id', function(SupplierOrder $model) {
                    $id='';   
                    $id .= '<a href="'.route('supplierOrder.show', $model->id).'">'.$model->supplier_order_id.'</a>';
                    return $id;
                })
               ->editColumn('supplier_id', function(SupplierOrder $model) {
                    $name  ='';   
                    $name .= '<a href="'.route('supplierOrder.show', $model->id).'">'.$model->business_name.'</a>';
                    return $name;
                })
               ->editColumn('reception_date', function(SupplierOrder $model) {
                   $date  = '';
                   $date .= (new Carbon\Carbon($model->reception_date))->format('d/m/Y'); 
                   return $date;
                })
               ->filterColumn('reception_date', function ($query, $keyword) {
                   $query->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(reception_date,'%d/%m/%Y') like ?", ["%$keyword%"]);
                })
               ->editColumn('fullfilment_request', function(SupplierOrder $model) {
                   $date  = '';
                   $date .= (new Carbon\Carbon($model->fullfilment_request))->format('d/m/Y'); 
                   return $date;
                })
               ->filterColumn('fullfilment_request', function ($query, $keyword) {
                   $query->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(fullfilment_request,'%d/%m/%Y') like ?", ["%$keyword%"]);
                })
               ->addColumn('days_to_expiration', function(SupplierOrder $model) {
                   $date  = '';
                   $today = Carbon\Carbon::today();
                   $fullfilment = Carbon\Carbon::parse($model->fullfilment_request);
                   $date .= $today->diffInDays($fullfilment, false); 
                   return ($date < 0 && $model->order_status == "Ricevuto") ? 'Chiuso' : $date ;
                })
               ->setRowClass(function (SupplierOrder $model) {
                   $date  = '';
                   $today = Carbon\Carbon::today();
                   $fullfilment = Carbon\Carbon::parse($model->fullfilment_request);
                   $date .= $today->diffInDays($fullfilment, false);
                   return ($date < 9 && $date > 3 && $model->order_status == "Da Ricevere")  ? 'bg-warning' :  (($date < 3 && $model->order_status == "Da Ricevere") ? 'bg-danger' : '');
                })
               ->rawColumns(['supplier_order_id','supplier_id','reception_date','fullfilment_request','days_to_expiration'])
               ->orderColumn('days_to_expiration','fullfilment_request $1')
               ->make(true);
    }

    /**
     * Get query source of dataTable.
     *
     * @param \App\User $model
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function query(SupplierOrder $model)
    {
        $query = SupplierOrder::join('suppliers','suppliers.supplier_id', '=' , 'supplier_orders.supplier_id')
                                ->select([
                                         'supplier_orders.id',
                                         'supplier_orders.supplier_order_id',
                                         'supplier_orders.reception_date',
                                         'supplier_orders.fullfilment_request',
                                         'suppliers.business_name',
                                         'order_status',
                                         'year'
                                        ]);

        return $this->applyScopes($query);
    }

    /**
     * Optional method if you want to use html builder.
     *
     * @return \Yajra\DataTables\Html\Builder
     */
    public function html()
    {
        return $this->builder()
                    ->ajax('')
                    ->columns($this->getColumns())
                    ->parameters([
                                    'scrollX' => 'true',
                                    'dom' => 'Bfrtip',
                                    'buttons' => ['pdf', 'excel', 'print'],
                                    'language' => [
                                        'searchPlaceholder' => 'Search...',
                                        'sSearch' => '',
                                        'lengthMenu'=> 'Mostra _MENU_ righe per Pagina',
                                    ],
                                 ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get columns.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getColumns()
    {
        return [
            'Codice Ordine'  => ['data' => 'supplier_order_id', 'name' => 'supplier_order_id'],
            'Fornitore'  => ['data' => 'supplier_id', 'name' => 'suppliers.business_name'],
            'Data Ricezione' => ['data' => 'reception_date', 'name' => 'reception_date'],
            'Data Richiesta Evasione'  => ['data' => 'fullfilment_request', 'name' => 'fullfilment_request'],
            'Giorni Mancanti' => ['data' => 'days_to_expiration', 'name' => 'days_to_expiration'],
            'Stato Ordine' => ['data' => 'order_status', 'name' => 'order_status'],
            'Anno' => ['data' => 'year', 'name' => 'year']
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get filename for export.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function filename()
    {
        return 'SuppliersOrders_' . date('YmdHis');
    }
}
```

### This is the View

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <!-- Required meta tags -->
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

            <!-- Meta -->
            <meta name="description" content="Premium Quality and Responsive UI for Dashboard.">
            <meta name="author" content="ThemePixels">

            <title>@yield('title')</title>

            <!-- vendor css -->
            <link href="{{asset('/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="{{asset('/lib/Ionicons/css/ionicons.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="{{asset('/lib/perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect-scrollbar.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="{{asset('/lib/highlightjs/github.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="{{asset('/lib/datatables/jquery.dataTables.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="{{asset('/lib/select2/css/select2.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.3/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">


                <!-- Starlight CSS -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('/css/starlight.css')}}">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('/css/table-style.css')}}">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('/css/style.css')}}">

            </head>

            <body>

<div class="sl-mainpanel">
    <div class="sl-pagebody">
        <div class="sl-page-title">
            <h3>Ordini Fornitori</h3>
            <hr>
        </div><!-- sl-page-title -->

        <div class="card pd-20 pd-sm-40">
            <div class="row pd-x-15 pd-b-30">
                <a href="{{route('client.create')}}" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-plus mg-r-5"></i> Nuovo Ordine Fornitore</a>
            </div>
            <div class="table-wrapper">
                {!! $dataTable->table() !!}
            </div><!-- table-wrapper -->
        </div><!-- card -->
    </div>
</div>


    <script src="{{asset('/lib/jquery/jquery.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('/js/loadingoverlay.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('/lib/popper.js/popper.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('/lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('/lib/perfect-scrollbar/js/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.js')}}"></script>

<script src="{{asset('/lib/highlightjs/highlight.pack.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('/lib/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('/lib/datatables-responsive/dataTables.responsive.js')}}"></script>



<script src="{{asset('/lib/select2/js/select2.min.js')}}"></script>

<script src="{{asset('/js/starlight.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('/js/dizorder/preload.js')}}"></script>


<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.3/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{asset('/vendor/datatables/buttons.server-side.js')}}"></script>
{!! $dataTable->scripts() !!}
</body>
</html>
```

The Result

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQ2rD.png)

Error Log

[ERR_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C69dd.png)

[ERR_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtMFB.png)

[ERR_3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuPta.png)

Laravel Error Log

```
[2018-12-13 00:50:50] local.ERROR: Method Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse::toJson does not exist. {"userId":1,"email":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com","exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException(code: 0): Method Illuminate\\Http\\JsonResponse::toJson does not exist. at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\Traits\\Macroable.php:99)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\yajra\\laravel-datatables-buttons\\src\\Services\\DataTable.php(181): Illuminate\\Http\\JsonResponse->__call('toJson', Array)
#1 [internal function]: Yajra\\DataTables\\Services\\DataTable->ajax()
#2 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#4 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#5 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(564): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#6 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\yajra\\laravel-datatables-buttons\\src\\Services\\DataTable.php(131): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#7 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\Orders\\SuppliersOrders.php(26): Yajra\\DataTables\\Services\\DataTable->render('layout.orders.s...')
#8 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\Orders\\SuppliersOrders->index(Object(App\\DataTables\\SuppliersOrdersDataTable))
#9 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller.php(54): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#10 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('index', Array)
#11 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(212): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\Orders\\SuppliersOrders), 'index')
#12 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(169): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#13 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(665): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#14 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#15 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#16 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#17 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#18 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate.php(43): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#19 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#20 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#21 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken.php(68): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#22 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#23 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#24 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#25 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#26 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#27 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php(63): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#28 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#29 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#30 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#31 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#32 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#33 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies.php(66): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#34 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#35 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#36 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#37 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(667): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#38 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(642): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#39 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(608): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#40 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(597): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#41 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#42 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#43 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#44 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#45 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#46 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(31): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#47 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#48 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#49 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(31): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#50 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#51 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#52 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#53 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#54 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#55 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(62): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#56 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#57 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#58 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#59 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#60 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#61 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ModaflexTEST\\public\\index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#62 {main}
"}
```

Can anyone help me with these?

Comment: Add the code of your related view to the question.

Comment: have edit the post by adding view

Comment: Did you looked in the JS Console?

Comment: @comm Yes it returns a 500 Internal Server Error. But it depends on the controller, i haven't found any documentation about Laravel 5.6

Comment: @Aciddiz Check laravel's error logs, a 500 should print something in there.

Comment: @Aciddiz Caps lock is not considered a good method of drawing attention to something.  On top of that, none of those are error logs.  Go to `storage/logs/laravel-log-name.log`, and paste the results of the contents of the file.  Not a screen shot; images aren't word-searchable.

Comment: @Daedalus Ok thanks for the tips. I added what you asked for.

Comment: @Aciddiz The most at this point I can recommend is to downgrade to the buttons version 2.x, because 3.x onwards uses `toJson`, where the method doesn't seem to exist.  I don't have the time to fully debug this beyond what I have already done.

Comment: @Daedalus thanks i have seen it but require a different Laravel version because button 2.0 works with 5.5.*.. i was trying to avoid that, but it seems the best option.